How to create iOS Settings table rows in SwiftUI List?
How can I create a traditional Settings-style table row in a SwiftUI List, where the row is laid out horizontally, with the title on the leading edge, and both a secondary text and a navigation chevron on the trailing edge?
Can I somehow use NavigationLink and/or another SwiftUI API do this?
Or do I have to cobble together my own custom view, to imitate NavigationLink's default appearance?


This is how a LabeledContent looks like in a list. The label is the black text on the leading edge, and the content is the grey text on the trailing edge.
The arrow on the trailing edge is how a NavigationLink looks, so all you need to do is to use a LabeledContent as the label of a NavigationLink.
NavigationLink {
    Text("Some Destination")
} label: {
    LabeledContent("Foo", value: "Bar")
}

Output:


A Picker with .navigationLink style also looks similar. The picker's label will be the black text, and the selected option is the grey text.
Picker("Foo", selection: $selection) {
    Text("Bar").tag(1)
    Text("Baz").tag(2)
}
.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)

But if you don't actually want a picker, and simply want the row to navigate to another view, using a Picker is not appropriate.
